# Using VBA in Excel to insert a missing value in a list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a complete newcomer to VBA so bear with me.

I have a list of consecutive integers with some values missing, also a list of missing values. These are columns A and B. What I'd like to be able to do is to search the list for the number that's one smaller than the value in the selected cell, insert a cell just below that number, and put the selected value into the new cell, then delete from the "missing values" list.

For example:
Say I have, in column A, the list: (1 2 3 5 6 9 10)
And in column B: (4 7 8)
What I'd like to be able to do is select the cell with "4" in it in column B, and have a sub that will:
1. Search the list in column A to find the cell containing "3"
2. Insert a cell in column A below the one containing "3", shifting the remainder down
3. Put "4" into the new column-A cell
4. Delete the cell containing "4" from column B, shifting the remainder up

I have over-simplified it ... I would like to do this with code because in reality my column-A list has nearly 10,000 entries, and my missing-value column-B list contains a few hundred.

I might be able to figure it on my own, but would appreciate something I didn't have to take weeks to tweak. Seems like if I knew more VBA it wouldn't be that difficult ... someday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This worked for me with your suggested data using your guidelines:

```
Private Sub fixList()
  ' Get reference to selected source cell
  Dim criteriaCell As Range
  Set criteriaCell = ActiveCell

  ' Get value of that cell to be found in search column
  Dim valueToLookFor As Long
  valueToLookFor = criteriaCell.Value - 1

  ' Get reference to matched cell in search column
  Dim foundCell As Range
  Set foundCell = Range("A:A").Find(valueToLookFor, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)

  ' If the search didn't come back with nothing, the search criteria was found
  If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then

    ' Insert a cell below the found cell and populate it with the search data
    foundCell.Select
    foundCell.Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    foundCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = criteriaCell.Value

    ' Delete the original criteriaCell
    criteriaCell.Select
    criteriaCell.Delete xlUp
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for not simply downvoting the question and moving on. I'll study the code also and learn what I can for the future, very helpful!

Comment: I have no idea ... someone else may have done it. It wasn't me, I tried to upvote it but apparently I haven't been around long enough to do so ... don't have enough "reputation"? I don't know. Anyway, know that your code is still working perfectly, and I, for one, appreciate your assistance!

Comment: No worries. Glad to help!

Comment: Done upvoting :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Interpolate() 
    Dim FirstR As Integer, FirstC As Integer 
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer 
    FirstR = ActiveCell.Row 
    FirstC = ActiveCell.Column 
    For c = 0 To Selection.Columns.Count - 1 
        For r = 0 To Selection.Rows.Count - 1 
            If Len(Cells(FirstR + r, FirstC + c)) = 0 Then 
                Cells(FirstR + r, FirstC + c).Value = _ 
                (Cells(FirstR + r - 1, FirstC + c) + _ 
                Cells(FirstR + r + 1, FirstC + c)) / 2 
                With Cells(FirstR + r, FirstC + c) 
                    .Font.Bold = True 
                    .Font.ColorIndex = 3 
                End With 
            End If 
        Next r 
    Next c 
End Sub
```